# Stuck on UEFI interactive shell of a VirtualBox VM running on Mac OS X 10.13 High Sierra 64-Bit

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

[image: screenshot]

I need to use a VM for a project with Xcode. I tried using VirtualBox VM with the stated OS model, but keep getting this error and am unsure how to proceed. I've never attempted this before and have done research but didn't quite understand. Any advice on the matter would be appreciated

Comment: How have you created the VM?

Comment: what is *the stated OS model*?

Comment: @JaromandaX its Mac OS X 10.13 High Sierra 64-bit

Comment: @harrymc What you're seeing is the VM if I'm not mistaken through the use of Oracle VM VirtualBox

Comment: Are the host and guest both Mac OS X 10.13? Could you add information about the definition of the VM (RAM, disk etc)?

Comment: I'm running the application on a windows 11 laptop as I want to use Xcode, I was mainly using default settings for disk but in terms of RAM, I used 16gb virtual

Comment: Oh, right, sorry, I thought that part was referring to the guest not the host - hang on ... so is it the guest or host that is Mac OS?

Comment: The guest is MAC OS being the VM I was trying to create, the host is a Windows 11 laptop

Comment: I ran into this issue and found that the best way was to just use VMWare as installing macOS in virtualbox Just Doesn't Work. VMWare player is free for non commercial use but if you like you can save out a VM file that is compatible with Virtualbox and use that once you have created the VM in VMWare.